# Prestashop 1.7 attribute groups - check stock and apply css to unavailable combination

Tags: attributes, prestashop, combinations, stock

Prestashop option to hide unavailable attributes on product page doesn't work when attribute groups are used, for example color and size (for clothing shops). 
I need to keep showing all possible combinations, but grey out (or strikethrough) the combinations with no stock. 
Like this:

[image]

I tried several things. 
In Prestashop 1.6 the following piece of code worked to apply css class (.out-of-stock-float-left) to unavailable combinations:

```
        {elseif $group.group_type == 'radio'}
            <ul id="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
                {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
                    {if {$group.attributes_quantity[{$id_attribute|intval}]} > 1} <!-- product in stock -->
                        <li class="input-container float-left">
                            <input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}"
                                    name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]"
                                    value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
                            <span class="radio-label">{$group_attribute.name}</span>
                        </li>
                    {else} <!-- product out of stock -->
                        <li class="input-container out-of-stock-float-left">
                            <input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}"
                                   name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]"
                                   value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
                            <span class="radio-label">{$group_attribute.name}</span>
                        </li>
                    {/if}
                {/foreach}
            </ul>
        {/if}
```

When changing combinations there is an ajax request. I don't know how to grey out combinations with no stock and make them not clickable.

Thanks

Comment: In PS 1.7 is far more complex. There is a module in Addons to do so.